# Access element by ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I accidentally discovered that you can access an element just by typing its id, e.g:

```
<input id="test" value="testValue"/>
<script>
   console.log(test.value); //testValue
</script>
```

Can anyone point me to where that feature is coming from?

Comment: It was something that Internet Explorer started doing way, way back, and a huge amount of code was written to expect that behavior so that's the way other browsers work now. It's a shame because it's an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: wow  that's amazing!

Comment: @vladimirs in addition, since you said it would be really hard to search this in Google, I give you a hint to do it yourself: http://goo.gl/6B0gS3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the spec:](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object)

> **window[name]**
>
> Returns the indicated element or collection of elements.
>
> As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this, use document.getElementById() or document.querySelector().